# Extract value of a textbox in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When I try to implement the below code in chrome or IE it works, but when I try in mozilla, it does not.

```
alert($("textarea[id*='TextBox1'").val());
```

In chrome and IE, I get the textbox value but in mozilla i do not get anything.
Nothing happens.

Can anyone please explain me the reason ?

Comment: selector not correct '$("textarea[id*='TextBox1']")'

Comment: Definitely need the missing square bracket ] after TextBox1'

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry for this silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your exact code, you are just missing an ending bracket between your ending quotes:

```
alert($("textarea[id*='TextBox1']").val());
```